# Alignment messed UP in Internet Explorer (is this a float issue?)

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

I am using a wordpress template and everything looks fine in FireFox.

But- Surprise, Surprise - it looks wrong in Internet Explorer 8

On this page there are two issues:

http://www.thebuddhagarden.com/blog/

1) The search box (which is supposed to be to the right in the navigation menu) is pushed DOWN so that it is hidden behind the word Categories.

2) And (probably related) the navigation menu (which starts with Blog Home, Shop Our Store, etc.,) is supposed to be aligned to the LEFT. Looks great in FireFox, but it is aligned center in IE8.

Comment: ODD, I don't see any alignment problems with IE8, until I switch to quirks mode.

Comment: Its working similar as FF in IE8 i guess you are saying about IE7

Comment: Hi again. I think you are right. I think I must still have IE7 on our store computer?!?! Because I looked at it at home and it looks fine and I just confirmed that I have IE8 at home. Do I need to worry about IE7? I know not many people use it.

Comment: Yes you need to worry about IE-7,there is fair amount who use IE-7 in-fact I would say for your practice you should make your site to each and every browser compatible, Its fun to see problems and get solution for the same,it teaches so many things about CSS and rarely IE8 get issues but IE-7 Does.This SO community helps alot in encountering bugs so just do this and if you get any issue ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not a float issue.

I figured 2 issues in IE-7 its working fine in IE-8.

do the followings

1.Remove line height:18px from your h1 this will show your title which is mixing with navigation in ie7.

2.Put width:690px (or your desired, obv it should be less then 695px) on your `<div id="navmenu-wrapper">` and things will be okay.

[image]

Comment: thanks a ton, Pankaj. I am surprised it works ok in IE8 for you because I see the problem in IE8. But thank you for your very easy to understand instructions and THANK YOU SO MUCH for taking a screen shot. It REALLY makes it more helpful. If I had enough reputation points to vote, I would vote your answer up, too.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't like elements that are floated right following elements that are floated left. I'm not sure why this is, but for some reason it considers right floats to be new line right floats. You have two options here.

Put the box-search div above the navmenu in your code. This should not have any affect on other browsers - FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera - they will all display it as they do now. IE, however, will allow your right float to be on the same line as your left float, thus fixing the issue.

Or, give your navmenu a specific width such that it uses all but the space needed by search, and float both left.

Comment: Thank you very much Lazerblade. I really appreciate the help. Internet Explorer is SUCH a pain, your tip really helps us out who are not that well versed at CSS (for the longest time I thought CSS was just a cop show on TV...)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of this property:

```
#navmenu ul {
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

On line 656 of your styles.css stylesheet. You're trying to center a list when you want to float it to the left, so just change it `margin:0` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you so much Andres!!! I forgot that when you put the margin: auto for the left and right margins it tries to center it. Thanks again. (I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation points to vote since I am so new to the forum. I an sorry.)

Comment: @user1344629 im glad it helped you, no need to vote up, just approve the answer by ticking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip. Had no idea what the check mark is for.